# What do we do when we don't understand the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

Well, this has happened to me a lot of times owing to my shallow knowledge of English. When I post questions, I get some great answers however, some of them contain a lot of jargon/terms/expression which I don't understand(even after a googling a lot of them) and obviously I would not able to make separate questions for all of them and neither can I keep badgering the person for clarification because of the fear of annoying the person with my curiosity or worse, getting the answer deleted. It is pretty unsettling when you don't completely understand the answer/comments or worse, the puns in speaker's comments. What do we do in this case?

One case would be "Ayn Rand certainly did, *you emoticon notwithstanding*." I didn't understand the words in italic. I know the meaning of each word but couldn't make out as a whole.

Comment: Are most of these comments coming from the same users?

Comment: @Robert it's already on http://english.stackexchange.com ([source](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279084/try-to-be-a-filter-not-a-sponge/279088#comment618333_279088))

Comment: The prior context helps. The commenter is referring to your previous use of an emoticon :-) and obliquely saying that emoticons don't change the meaning of things. I think that *you* is a typo for *your* which makes parsing the commenters meaning more difficult. This is all off-topic here though. For what it's worth, I'm a native speaker of English and I don't find the comment at all clear.

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, not anyone in particular.

Comment: @RobertLongson Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Personally, I simply back off.

Not sure it's the best course of action, but when I realize that it's going to take lots of comments and possibly lots of time and efforts, without any real gain, I just back off and doesn't keep pondering about it.

I've been there more than once. Sometimes it has happy ending, you realize what the other user meant and you both end with "cheers". However, most of the times it's being dragged and with each additional comment, you only get more frustrated.

So unless the part you don't understand is critical (in most cases it's not), just back off, don't post anything, or post something like "OK, thanks for your answer" and that's it. If you feel like the comments you already left have no value for others, you can delete them as well, and usually the other user will notice and delete his/her own comments afterwards.

---

<sub>And, before you ask: TL;DR means  "Too Long, Didn't Read" which means a short summary of a longer answer. :)</sub>

Comment: hahaha, I will know what to do from next time. thanks :)

Comment: lol, better wait for more opinions but thanks!